# How to compile a gradle project to exe with gradle-launch4j plugin

Tags: java, gradle, javafx, launch4j

I have created a JavaFX application with Gradle and would like to export it to exe along with all its dependencies and also the JRE, what is the best way to go about this?

I have tried using the quickstart provided by Gradle-launch4j but the exe doesn't launch, it does launch in the IDE and when I run from the command line 
I get error  `JavaFX modules are needed to run the application`

This is my build.gradle script

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.5'
    id 'edu.sc.seis.launch4j' version '2.4.6'
}

group 'Starter Apps'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 11
mainClassName = "$moduleName/controllers.Main"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile (group: 'com.jfoenix', name: 'jfoenix', version: '9.0.8'){
        exclude group: 'org.openjfx'
    }
    compile ('de.jensd:fontawesomefx-controls:11.0'){
        exclude group: 'org.openjfx'
    }
    compile ('de.jensd:fontawesomefx:8.9'){
        exclude group: 'org.openjfx'
    }
    compile ('de.jensd:fontawesomefx-icons525:4.6.3'){
        exclude group: 'org.openjfx'
    }
    compile (group: 'com.sun.mail', name: 'javax.mail', version: '1.6.2'){
        exclude group: 'org.openjfx'
    }
}

//create a single Jar with all dependencies
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Jar File Example',
                'Implementation-Version': version,
                'Main-Class': "controllers.Main"
    }
    baseName = project.name + '-all'
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}


javafx {
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml' ]
    version = '11.0.+'
}

launch4j {
    headerType='console'
    outfile = "Burj2.exe"
    icon = "${projectDir}/src/main/resources/images/icon.ico"
    jar = '../libs/Master_Mode_System_Config-all-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar'
}
```

And heres my module-info.java

```
module Master_Mode_System_Config {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires java.mail;
    requires com.jfoenix;

    opens controllers to javafx.fxml;
    exports controllers;
}
```

App runs fine on the IDE and I'm really confused as to why this is a problem.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the error/exception do you get ?

Comment: ```JavaFX modules are needed to run the application``` from powershell

Answer (score 0):

Update your build.gradle with the following changes. Since it is a JavaFx application, it cannot be console type. It should be **gui** type which I have updated below. You have to provide the **main class name** (class name having main method) with complete package name. Once you run, you will be able to see the exe file and you can launch it.

```
launch4j {
    headerType="gui"
    mainClassName = <provide your main class name>
    outfile = "Burj2.exe"
    icon = "${projectDir}/src/main/resources/images/icon.ico"
    jar = '../libs/Master_Mode_System_Config-all-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar'
}
```

Comment: Nothing errors from cmd or powershell after bundling it as gui but the program still doesn't run. Switched back to console and got ```Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application```

Answer (score 0):

How I solved **Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application**:

1. Create a new class (e.g. `Main`) which not extends `Application` with a main method.
2. Call `App.main` (App extends Application) method from `Main.main`.
3. Now run the app calling `Main.main`.

```java
public class App extends Application {
    [...]
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    [...]
}
public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        App.main(args);
    }
}
```